# Can't download Flutter download button fail

Tags: flutter

im trying to download the Flutter SDK for debian based linux distribution (Distributor ID:  Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:    2019.1
Codename:   n/a) But the download button shows fail
¿Has anyone found the download url?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a VPN connection and then refresh the page, this problem happens when you try to download Flutter SDK from an embargoed country. You can confirm this by going to the [SDK Archive](https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/sdk/archive?tab=linux) and if you try to download any package you will get this error:

```
  <Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
     <Message>Access denied.</Message>
     <Details>We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location</Details>
  </Error>
```

Comment: Thanks!, in my case it was the opposite not using it XD

Comment: if I don't want to use VPN, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by using mirror sites without VPN. Just download the sdk from git and use 2 Environment User Path variables

> PUB_HOSTED_URL
>   set user path: https://pub.flutter-io.cn

and

> FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL
>   set user path: https://storage.flutter-io.cn

Restart your computer after setting these two Environment variables. Please follow [this](https://flutter.dev/community/china).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below link: 
https://flutter.dev/community/china

Then download one version from Original URL or Minorred URL